# foo.find(...).execFind is not a function - mongoose schema model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have defined a custom type and I am trying to return all entries from mongo contained in the referenced collection:

Participant.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var participantSchema= new Schema({
    email: String,
});

module.exports =  mongoose.model('Participant', participantSchema, 'participants')
```

api.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Participant = require('../models/Participant');

router.get('/all', function(req, res) {
    var participant = mongoose.model('Participant');
    //var participant = new Participant();
    console.log(participant);
    participant.find().execFind(function (arr,data) {
        res.send(data);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

But due something fishy, my model does not extend (I assume the default prototype)

```
 participant.find(...).execFind is not a function

TypeError: participant.find(...).execFind is not a function
    at /Users/bogdan/private/appName/routes/api.js:13:24
```

Any help is highly appreciated... 
Thanks

Comment: Try calling [`exec`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) instead of `execFind`.

Comment: thanks, add a comment, and maybe you could explain me what is the difference :p

Comment: `execFind` was removed back in one of the 3.x releases, not exactly sure when. Anyway, it's been replaced by `exec`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`execFind` was replaced with [`exec`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) back in one of the 3.x releases of Mongoose.

So you must now call `exec` instead of `execFind`.